# Is `__proto__` safe to use as a property name for objects created using `Object.create(null)`?

Tags: javascript, object, dictionary, properties, prototype

The context of this question is implementing dictionaries that have no restrictions on what keys can be placed in them (and no funny behavior).

Of course, if you use objects which inherit from `Object.prototype`, you can get [funny behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) if you try and set `__proto__`.

So the question is, if you create an object that doesn't inherit from `Object.prototype`, is there anything special about the `__proto__` property, and is it as safe to use as any other property name?  For example, on my browser `__proto__` seems to be "unsafe" on "normal" objects, but "safe" on `Object.create(null)` objects:

```
var normal = {};
Object.getPrototypeOf(normal) !== Array.prototype
normal['__proto__'] = Array.prototype;
Object.getPrototypeOf(normal) === Array.prototype // prototype **is** changed

var odd = Object.create(null);
Object.getPrototypeOf(odd) === null
odd['__proto__'] = Array.prototype;
Object.getPrototypeOf(odd) === null // prototype **not** changed
```

To confuse me more, [this](https://github.com/domenic/dict/blob/master/dict.js) dictionary library uses `Object.create(null)`, but also mangles the keys by prepending a `~`.  Does this mean that it is not safe, in general across implementations, to use arbitrary keys in objects created with `Object.create(null)`?

Comment: [Here is some relevant reading material.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)

Comment: @Pointy already read it -- but I did not see how it answers my question.

Comment: @Pointy to elaborate on why I don't think it answers my question -- it provides an example using `Object.create(null)` but makes no statement about the exact behavior of the created object.

Answer (score 1):

As I have [recently learnt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23521314), `__proto__` is not in itself a special property; rather the `__proto__` property of the `Object` prototype is, and by extension the `__proto__` property of any object ultimately inheriting it from the `Obejct` prototype. As this is not the case for objects created with `Object.create(null)`, `__proto__` is just like any other property for them. (And as the example in the question linked to above shows, this can also be acheived for objects originally inheriting from `Object` by disconnecting them from the prototype chain with `myObejct.__proto__ = null`.)