# __proto__ doesn't seem to work after a null assignment - bug or feature?

Tags: javascript

I have observed a behaviour regarding `__proto__` which seems weird to me: when changing `__proto__` to various objects it behaves as expected, but once it is set to `null` changing it again to another object doesn't seem to have an effect.

Is this a bug in the implementation, or the desired behaviour? If this is the desired behaviour, can someone shed a light as to why?

An example JavaScript code (all the tests pass fine until the last line):

```
p = {
  sum: function() {
    return this.x + this.y;
  }
};

o = {
  x: 1,
  y: 2
};

o.sum(); // As expected: TypeError: o.sum is not a function

// These all behave as expected:
o.__proto__ = p;
o.__proto__; // [object Object]
o.__proto__.sum; // [object Function]
o.sum(); // returns 3 :-)

// These all behave as expected:
o.__proto__ = {};
o.__proto__; // [object Object]
o.sum(); // TypeError: o.sum is not a function

// These all behave as expected:
o.__proto__ = p;
o.__proto__; // [object Object]
o.__proto__.sum; // [object Function]
o.sum(); // returns 3 :-)

// Still behaves more or less as expected:
o.__proto__ = null;
o.__proto__; // undefined (why undefined and not null?)
o.sum(); // TypeError: o.sum is not a function

// Seems fine, until the last line:
o.__proto__ = p;
o.__proto__; // [object Object]
o.__proto__.sum; // [object Function]
o.sum(); // Expected 3, but... TypeError: o.sum is not a function
```

I'm working with Firefox 28.0; don't know how other browsers react.

Comment: How exactly are you running the test? I mean you can't continue the test after the first `TypeError`, so are you running it again with that line commented out?

Comment: @cookie: I'm running it line by line on the web console :)

Comment: I see it happening. Seems the prototypal inheritance is permanently broken on `o` as soon as you assign `.__proto__ = null`. It can't even get native methods like `.hasOwnProperty()` after you reassign `p`. Though `__proto__` is non-standard, so I don't know that it could be called a bug.

Comment: @cookiemonster: Regarding non-standardness, it comes in [ES6](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-\_\_proto\_\__-property-names-in-object-initializers).

Comment: Ah, I know what the  issue is. It's because `__proto__` is implemented as a getter/setter on Object.prototype, so when you got rid of the prototype chain, you got rid of `__proto__`. Try this: `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.prototype, "__proto__").set.call(o, p)`

Comment: @FelixKling: Yes, it is coming (to browsers anyway) unless they manage to yank it. :-)

Comment: See also: [Is `__proto__` safe to use as a property name for objects created using `Object.create(null)`?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22512329/1048572)

Comment: Thanks, @Bergi - the link in the comments there added a bit of insight, and hopefully me answering there is useful for the community too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `__proto__` in Firefox is an actual property on `Object.prototype` implemented with `getter/setter` functions. So when you set the `__proto__` of `o` to `null`, you wiped out the entire prototype chain, which included the `__proto__` property.

Now when you assign to `__proto__`, you're just assigning a new, normal property that doesn't have the desired behavior directly to the `o` object.

---

So in order to get the functionality of `__proto__`, you'll need to go to `Object.prototype`, and borrow the `.set` method of the `__proto__` property, and use `.call` to allow it to operate on the `o` object.

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.prototype, "__proto__").set.call(o, p);
```

So this invokes the `set` function of `Object.prototype.__proto__` using `.call` so that the `o` becomes the `this` value of `set`, and `p` is the value being set. This will make `__proto__` operate on `o` as though it was a property of `o`, allowing it to set the internal `[[Prototype]]` property.

---

Note that this is only tested in Firefox.