# Why is __proto__ undefined for Object.create(null)?

Tags: javascript, prototype, v8

While reading on Javascript's prototypes I encountered this behaviour I can't explain. I am testing this in chrome's console (which is V8).

```
var fruit = {taste:'good'};
var banana = Object.create(fruit);
console.log(banana.taste); //"good"
console.log(banana.__proto__); //Object {taste: "good"}
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(banana)); //Object {taste: "good"}
```

So far everything is as expected.
However if I do this:

```
var drink = Object.create(null);
Object.defineProperty(drink, 'taste', {value:"nice"});
var coke = Object.create(drink);
console.log(coke.taste); //"nice"
console.log(coke.__proto__); //undefined
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(coke)); //Object {taste: "nice"}
```

then `coke.__proto__ === undefined`. Why is it `undefined` in the second case?

Comment: So this isn't actually a bug. __proto__ is undefined because __proto__ comes from Object.prototype. In the second case Object.prototype is not in the prototype chain, because chain ends with null

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is `__proto__` safe to use as a property name for objects created using `Object.create(null)`?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22512329/1048572) or [Why the prototype can be retrieved but the `__proto__` is undefined in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31159621/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi I think this is the cleanest of the question of the bunch, and I'd nominate it for a master duplicate. However, I answered the question (but I also answered one of your proposed duplicates as well) so I might be biased. I'd also be happy to take it to JavaScript chat or meta, to get a few more voices, if you think that's better.

Comment: @apsillers: Actually I don't mind whether they're closed as dupes or not (rather not, they're not exactly the same), I only wanted to interlink them. I just used the standard slang in a comment, instead of voting to close (which would have hammered them).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I once [opened an issue for this behavior](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=506166), but it was closed as standards-compliant behavior. According to the issue's close reason:

> This is working as specified. ES6 `__proto__` is a getter defined on Object.prototype. For an object that doesn't have that in its prototype chain it is not accessible (just like, say, hasOwnProperty isn't). You need to use Object.getPrototypeOf instead.

This is indeed true: [ES6 section B.2.2.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.prototype.__proto__) defines `Object.prototype.__proto__`; therefore, the `__proto__` property is inherited from `Object.prototype`. However, your `drink` object was created with `Object.create(null)`, so it doesn't have `Object.prototype` in its prototype chain.

An object always has internal knowledge to its prototype, stored in its [[[Prototype]] internal slot](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots). The `__proto__` property is a way to access that internally-known prototype through code. An object's lack of a `__proto__` property does not affect its [[Prototype]] slot, which still exists.

To be perfectly clear: `coke` *does* have a prototype (stored in [[Prototype]]), and that prototype is the object `drink`. You can see this with `Object.getPrototypeOf(coke)`. However, that is the entire prototype chain, because the prototype of `drink` is `null`. Therefore, `coke` can't inherit `__proto__` from `Object.prototype.__proto__` because it doesn't have `Object.prototype` in its prototype chain.

Comment: I thought that `__proto__` is the actual reference to the prototype object. If `__proto__ === undefined` then how `Object.getPrototypeOf()` knows that `drink` is `coke`'s prototype? I am guessing V8 internally doesn't use `__proto__` then

Comment: @potato300 I just asked the same question. The `coke` has a `prototype` indeed, the `drink` object. But the `drink` object doesn't have a prototype (it is `null`), so the link to `__proto__` cannot be reached by the chain.

Comment: @potato300 Correct; it uses [[Prototype]], which is a internal slot that allows the object to always know its own prototype. The [[Prototype]] value is not directly accessible through code.