# Why does [[prototype]] has two level of __proto__ in javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

When we create an object and look at the `[[prototype]]` of it, there is a `__proto__` property and even further we expand there is the same set of properties with another `__proto__` but with the null value.

What is the reason for these two levels of `__proto__` and why it is null in the second occurrence?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)

Comment: Namely, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/572897) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35458348/21305238) which is linked from the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, that's really confusing. [`__proto__` is a (deprecated) getter/setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto), and expanding it in the console will run the getter *on the start of the prototype chain*. It then returns `Object.protype`, and expanding `__proto__` on that result object will now result in `null`.

But my advice is to completely ignore `__proto__`. It is deprecated and should not be used anywhere, in the console only look at the *[[prototype]]* which displays the prototype chain links.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take an example to illustrate what happens internally:

1. Define an ordinary object a `const a = {}` which is Sugar syntax for `const a = new Object()`
2. [new operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new#description) points a[[prototype]] to `Object.prototype`. `a[[prototype]] = Object.prototype`
3. [Object.prototype](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-properties-of-the-object-prototype-object) has a `[[prototype]]` which value is `null`
4. So `a[[prototype][[prototype]]` => `Object.prototype[[prototype]]` => `null`